# Browser needs to resize by itself when URL starts with m.(website).com

Tags: javascript, eclipse, selenium

I just want to resize my window to mobile size when URL changes to m.(website).com . **Can any one help me out with selenium codes which can resize its browser window automatically on detecting the URL ,if the URL starts with m.(website).com**

Answer (score 0):

Please find the sample code below:

```
String url = "http://m.google.com/";
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
if(url.startsWith("m.")) {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi karthi, thank you for your valuable code.Which was very helpful for me